# No data received in simple socket chat

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, chat

i am trying to write a simple client-server one-way chat (just for learning purpose) but i am stuck at the very beginning. These are codes for both server and client

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), bind(), and connect() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for perror() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit() */
#include <string.h>

#define MYPORT 3490

int main(int argc, char *argv){

struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
int sockfd;
int newsockfd;
socklen_t clilen;
int n;
char client_message[2000];

//socket declaration
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

//filling struct
my_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_port=htons(MYPORT);
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
memset(& (my_addr.sin_zero), '0', 8);

//binding socket to address and port
if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)& my_addr, sizeof(my_addr))<0)
    printf("Bind error");

//listening on the socket
listen(sockfd, 5);
printf("Waiting for connection...\n");
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

//accepting connection
if (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)& cli_addr, &clilen) <0){  
    printf("Unable to connect\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Connected with %s\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
}

 while( (n = recv(newsockfd , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {

        printf(client_message);
    }

 if(n == 0)
    {
        printf("Client disconnected");
    }
    else if(n == -1)
    {
        printf("recv failed");
    }

}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), bind(), and connect() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

int n;
int client;
int dest_port = 3490;
char buffer[1000];

struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
printf("Socket created\n");

server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port=htons(dest_port);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero),'0',8);

if(connect(client, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))<0)
    printf("Connection error");
printf("Connected with server\n");

 while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        scanf("%s" , buffer);

        //Send some data
        if( send(client , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0) < 0)
        {
            printf("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The server output as following:

```
Waiting for connection...
Connected with 127.0.0.1
recv failed
```

when output of client

```
Socket created
Connected with server
Enter message :
```

I have spent hours reading tutorials, man pages and others and I really can`t solve this. The issue seems to be not as much complicated, so the more upset I am. 
Moreover, when trying to send from server and receive in client, I have got "send failed" on the server side.

EDIT: 
After using perror and finding out what "socket operation on non-socket" means I figure it out that a problem was

```
if (newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)& cli_addr, &clilen) <0)
```

Which first coompare "accept..." with "0" and then assign the result of comparison to `newsockfd`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you printed the actual error when a system call like `recv` fails. Print the value of `errno`, or use `perror` to print a nice message describing the error.

Comment: And unrelated to your current problem, but think about the length reported by `strlen`... It does not include the string terminator. What happens in the server when you try to print the *unterminated* string you received?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as for `strlen`, I am not sure what happens in the server when I would try on to print the unterminated string, I will try to figure it out. Should I use `sizeof` instead?

Comment: As for proper way to showing errors (sorry for being newbie) Using `perror`: `recv failed: Socket operation on non-socket`

Comment: Ok, everything is working fine. I have figure it out by google "Socket operation on non-socket". Thank you anyway @Someprogrammerdude to show me how important is being patient and to properly debug the program :)

Comment: Send `strlen(...) + 1` instead, and the terminator will be sent with the string.